# AWS lamda deployment for python code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, virtualenv

I wrote a python code in my windows m/c and included the dependencies by creating virtualenv and copying \Lib\site-packages.
When i am able to run this code successfully from my windows m/c but when I deployed in AWS lambda then getting "No module named 'pyodbc'" error.
Do i need to include any other packages for aws lambda deployment? 
I am creating virtual env in my windows platform.

Comment: How are you installing the packages?
How are you deploying to AWS?
you can checkout this guide https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/

Comment: i am following this step: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error, and in my case, it was because of cross-packages imports, which for me worked differently locally vs on the cloud.

For example, I had a structure similar to the one below:

```
src:
  package1:
     - file_a.py
        - ClassA
  package2:
     - file_b.py
        - ClassB
```

...and I had to import Class_A into Class_B. Locally the imports in classB were looking something like this:

```
from src.package1.file_a import ClassA
```

in my case after deployment to the cloud, it did not see anymore the 'src', as there the root package had no name.

the workaround was to wrap ClassB imports into try - except. In the except block I used same imports statements without 'src.' part, like this:

```
try:
   # works locally
   from src.package1.file_a import ClassA
except:
   # works on the cloud
   from package1.file_a import ClassA
```